# How does my app work in iOS simulator if architecture is set to arm?

Tags: ios, xcode

My build settings has "architecture" option set set several arm versions. That means after compilation and linking I should get fat binary for several ARMs.

But how then it works in my iOS simulator which is x86 based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode will always build your app for x86_64 when you change the target to be the simulator, your choice of VALID_ARCHITECTURE have no impact on this.

Comment: Target? Do you mean "destination"?

Comment: Deployment target, aka. the dropdown box in the top left corner of Xcode.